# Worker Thread iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading

I want to create a background thread on the iPhone that executes some code every 10msec.
But before I get lost in the concurrency programming guide and the threading programming guide of apple **again**, I wanted to ask whether someone here can help me out.
What I want to do:

- Create a background worker thread
- Trigger the execution of a method every 10msec. (probably by using a NSTimer in that thread?)
- Put as less load on the main application thread as possible

In my understanding subclassing `NSThread` and writing my own main method in that subclass should do the trick. That way I don't use an `NSTimer` for the update intervals but something like:

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 0.01];
```

Also queuing mechanisms between main thread and worker thread don't make any sense, as the worker thread should perform the same operation over and over - until stopped.

The question is: How can I configure the thread to use a timer? I can't see how I can attach a `NSTimer` to that worker threads Run Loop?

Comment: Nsoperation is a single use object. Once it executes, it's gone. You can recreate the operation objects on a timer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's possible to do this using the method you outline, but have you looked at using Grand Central Dispatch? It can make some of this a lot easier:

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
    while ([self shouldKeepProcessingInBackground]) {
        [self doBackgroundWork];
        usleep(1e4);
    }
})
```

You can also use a timer dispatch source to do work periodically:

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_source_t timerSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, backgroundQueue);
dispatch_source_set_timer(timerSource, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0), 0.01*NSEC_PER_SEC, 0*NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timerSource, ^{
    [self doBackgroundWork];
});
dispatch_resume(timerSource);
```

Comment: don't use usleep(), though.  Use any of the built in timer like primitives instead as they are much more efficient (as you show in your second example).

Comment: Andrew Madsens second suggestion; using grand central dispatch, dispatch_resume(timerSource); and dispatch_suspend(timerSource); worked out very good for my purposes

Answer (score 2):

NSRunLoop is the missing link.

You will have to setup the thread's run loop to repeat, or you can control this from your thread's entry. the thread hosts the timer (the timer will die with the run loop if it's still alive).

NSRunLoop is a pretty small class - check it and the related samples out.

Comment: that is what i tried to understand. but i can't understand it :( how do i set up the threads run loop to repeat? from where? the original thread? what do you mean by 'from your threads entry' - start of the main method of my NSThread subclass? hm, i'll search the examples for help

Comment: you need to give it a source and/or timer and/or direct it to run. telling it to run is probably the short answer. if it has no input, then it stops (and the thread would then close). for this, you would interact with run loops from the thread it is bound to. i looked into this: CFRunLoop is a much better introduction on the subject, and there are numerous samples (see the OS X reference too). 'your thread's entry' refers to its entry point. this is the part of the program where the thread has been created and your callback/message is made. since you have subclassed NSThread, `-main` is it.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily use GCD (grand central dispatch) for that. First create a selector that will be called in the background. From here call whatever method you want.

```
- (void)backgroundSelector
{
    // do whatever you want to do
    [self performSelector:@selector(backgroundSelector) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
}
```

After that just fire this method for the first time like this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    [self backgroundSelector];
});
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple and clean if you do it with NSThread. With no need to subclass it.

```
- (void)backgroundStuff {
    while (!self.cancelThread) {
        // do your work
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.01];
    }
}
```

Just an ordinary function. cancelThread is a member variable you declare. Start it with

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(backgroundStuff) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

and you can cancle the thread anytime with self.cancelThread = true;

Comment: that's the solution i'm using now. and it doesn't work sufficiently. that's why i want a better background thread implementation, including the Run Loop configuration or whatever it takes.