# How to manage data from web service to make application fast and smooth

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working in an application in which I Am getting data from web service in json format for each and every page and also sending data to remote data base.In this process my application is getting slow .Until the data is fetched from web service  the next view is not loaded.It is consuming a lot of time, is there any way to fetch data and show view simultaneously.I heard about thread programing but I Am not familiar with it .Please suggest me  which technique I should adopt to make my application faster.any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your purposes, it would be easiest to just use the standard `NSURLConnection`. It is asynchronous out of the box. In the completion handler you can e.g. update your UI, or notify it to update itself.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
   [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
   queue:self.queue
   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
       // do something with data or handle error
   }];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Grand Central Dispatch or an NSInvocationOperation to do the loading in a background thread:

```
dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0);
dispatch_queue_t main = dispatch_get_main_queue();
dispatch_async(q, ^{
    PagedSearchResult *result = // something which takes a while to complete
    dispatch_sync(main, ^{
        // update the UI
    });
});
```

Take a look at [Ray Wenderlich's Grand Central Dispatch tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

Fo this you can do like
do your all downloading and uploading of data in background process so user does not need to wait until the data completed them task.

for background process you can easily use with

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(runProcessInBackground:) withObject:nil];
```

or you also can refer this
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949248/iphone-sdk-running-a-repeating-process-in-a-background-thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949248/iphone-sdk-running-a-repeating-process-in-a-background-thread)

and also u can use pagination in the appliaction for displaying data like in first call u will just receive first 100 records from the web service so that will take small time period and after 100 fetched then load another when page come in end so with this also u can increase your app. speed.

hope this will help you.

Comment: how can i load data in back ground and at the same time i want to display some  downloaded data in table view give some code what i will do inside runProcessInBackground: .

Comment: for that u can do like feel some array or dic. when downloading data and display that data and after some time reload it so it will feel other data which downloaded so like this u can display and downloading both can do at once.