# Objective C Class/Object in own thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, class, queue

I need to write a Objcetive-C class (then an object). This object must live in his own thread in order to make calculation cycle ( and then all his methods/functions ) without being affected from GUI events. is there a safe way to write a class like this?

Comment: use the Grand Central Dispatch for this. maybe this helps you: http://jeffreysambells.com/2013/03/01/asynchronous-operations-in-ios-with-grand-central-dispatch

Comment: You also should distinguish if your object "must live in his own thread" or what you are really wanting is that the calculation is executed in it's own thread. Additionally, where do you expect your result? In the object? Or will there be a completion block to facilitate this?

Answer (score 0):

Apple uses GCD (Grand Central Dispatch) to handle threading-operations in iOS. In your case, the `dispatch_get_global_queue` might be the correct GCD-operation for your use-case. An example (quoted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759264/worker-thread-ios)):

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
    while ([self shouldKeepProcessingInBackground]) {
        [self doBackgroundWork];
        usleep(1e4);
    }
})
```

Comment: A thread should never run a loop all the time.  It eats battery and CPU.  Instead, block on some kind of a signaling mechanism (of which GCD provides several).